# How do I configure a whitelist of SSL/TLS protocols in uWSGI?

Tags: ssl, tls, uwsgi

I can specify a list of ciphers using `https = =0,x.crt,x.key,<ciphers>`. Documentation for that is here: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/HTTPS.html#setting-ssl-tls-ciphers

But is there also a way to specify which SSL/TLS protocols are allowed?

I want to disable SSLv2 and SSLv3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From reading the [`uwsgi` source code](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi), it looks like SSLv2 is automatically disabled, and that SSLv3 can be disabled using the `"ssl-enable3"` configuration option.  The optional *ciphers* string, while useful, cannot really be used for whitelisting (or disabling) the SSL/TLS protocol versions used by `uwsgi`, only the cipher suites.

To see that SSLv2 support is disabled, we start with the [`uwsgi_opt_https`](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/plugins/http/https.c#L13) function, which parses the `"https"` option.  After parsing the certificate, key, cipher suite, *etc*, this function [calls `uwsgi_ssl_new_server_context`](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/plugins/http/https.c#L53).

The `uwsgi_ssl_new_server_context` function is defined [here](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/core/ssl.c#L203).  Of particular interest are the [default SSL option flags](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/core/ssl.c#L218), which *include* `SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2`.  And, most interestingly, we see that the `SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3` option flag (for disabling SSLv3 support) will also be used, but [only if this `uwsgi.sslv3` variable is set to false](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/core/ssl.c#L224).

How can `uwsgi.sslv3` be set to false?  For that, we see [here](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/core/uwsgi.c#L701) that there is an `"ssl-enable3"` option that you can set in the `uswgi` configuration:

```
[uwsgi]
...
ssl-enable3 = false
```

Now, for bonus points, you might *also* want to disable TLSv1, and whitelist just TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2.  For accomplishing this, you'd have to do the above *and* use the [`"ssl-option"`](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/core/uwsgi.c#L702) configuration option, *e.g.*:

```
[uwsgi]
...
ssl-enable3 = false
ssl-option = 67108864
```

How did I come up with that magic number "67108864"?  The `"ssl-option"` option takes a *number*, not a string.  Thus we need to the name of the OpenSSL flag we want to set, then determine the numeric value of that flag.
So first I had to look at the OpenSSL [`SSL_CTX_set_options`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_options.html) documentation to see that I wanted the value of the `SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1` flag.   The numeric value is found in the [OpenSSL source code](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/include/openssl/ssl.h#L438): `0x04000000U`.  But `uwsgi` wants an integer value for `"ssl-option"`, not hexadecimal, thus:

```
$ perl -e 'print int(0x04000000), "\n";'
67108864
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: just FYI, ssl-enable3 = false does not work. This option does not accept arguments. i.e., it can only be used to enable the option, not disable it

Answer (score 0):

Just to addition previous answer.
You have to specify ssl-option in uwsgi config before https-socket option.
Otherwise your ssl configuration won't make any effect.